# How to treat wrong historical data in big data?

Tags: database, apache-spark, hdfs, bigdata

I have collected a lot of data in the cluster. I know that it is not recommended to update the previous data, but there are errors in the historical data. I need to recalculate based on the new correct original data, but the calculated results conflict with the historical data. Because they have unique index conflicts.

In this case, what are the common solutions?

Should I delete the historical error data directly?

Comment: I am not sure which tool you are working on but from my experience on hive I would recommend you to do following if your data is not partitioned then partition it is such way may be on date or any other key such that there can be distinct partitions which you know have faulty data then you can simple overwrite them with the new data. In Big Data idea of doing update like a CRUD operation is not recommend

Comment: take a backup and delete.

Comment: Very depends on the use case. What partitioning do you have? Is it a one-time situation (that recalculation required) or it's a pretty common thing that you want to automatise?